# Plain simple scrollbar in CSS for a webpage

Tags: css

I searched this site and google and found no way to simply add a plain simple scrollbar to my webpage. Is there no such way? I'm rendering a web page and there is no scrollbar. Can't understand why the default behavior is faulty. Default is you want a scrollbar for overflow but no, with CSS everything has to be tricks and workarounds.

Comment: The scrollbar should appear if the page is longer than the viewport. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We can't explain *why the default behavior is faulty* either, because you've not included any code. There's no *tricks and workarounds* involved in getting the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you probably looking for a way to *always* have a scrollbar present, also if the page is *short enough* to not have one?

Then, yes there is a way. You might wanna do:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I understand why one would do so. 
It prevents jumps when navigating between pages, which have enough content to show a scrollbar and pages which do not.